# Weak energy condition is violated: which are the consequences?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I am studying [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.08828) paper: *Non-singular rotating black hole with a time delay in the center* by T. de Lorenzo et al.

In this paper, the authors introduce a new metric for a non singular, rotating black hole. They find that the Kretschmann scalar of their solution is bounded (although not continuous) and they find that the weak energy condition is violated inside the horizon. Which could be the consequences of this violation?